# Blessing on Star Anise

Tags: halacha, blessing, fruits, smell, spices

Star anise is technically the fruit of the evergreen tree *[Illicium verum](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Illicium_verum)*. However, this fruit is not used as an edible fruit, only as a spice.

**What blessing do the authorities determine is the right one to recite before smelling it?**

I would think *hanosein reiach tov bapeiros* because it is a fruit.

I would think *borei atzei vesamim* because it is an inedible tree part.

I would think *borei minei vesamim* because it is indeterminable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Star anise**, see the comment-section in [this article](https://din.org.il/2021/11/25/%D7%91%D7%A8%D7%9B%D7%AA-%D7%94%D7%A8%D7%99%D7%97-%D7%9B%D7%95%D7%9B%D7%91-%D7%90%D7%A0%D7%99%D7%A1/) where it is said that the blessing should be  בורא עצי בשמים, as found in [Shulchan Aruch , Orach Chayim, Siman 216](https://www.sefaria.org/Shulchan_Arukh%2C_Orach_Chayim.216.2?lang=bi&with=all&lang2=en).

For reference - [According to Dinonline](https://dinonline.org/2011/05/23/smelling-anisemint/), a person should make the בורא עשבי בשמים - borei isvei besamim - blessing upon smelling **anise** (not star anise) because it's a spice.

This, however, only applies when you want to smell the fragrance:

> Note that one only makes a berachah upon smelling tea with the intention of enjoying its scent. If one takes the tea to drink it, and only smells the scent inadvertently, one would not make a blessing.

Comment: that link is about anise not star anise.

Comment: I have edited the answer so that the part that deals with "star anise" (which is the question) comes first.

Comment: That's better indeed!